# C++ UTF-8 encoding with Wininet

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, utf-8, wininet

I’m having some problems with encoding while reading webpage through Wininet.
That’s what I’m doing:

```
char receivedContent[16344];
InternetReadFile(hInternetRequest, receivedContent, 16344, &charsRead);
```

Problem occurs when I try to output received characters to console, or Windows controls (MessageBox for example) where every non-ANSI character becomes \uXXXX.

I also tried using MultiByteToWideChar() function, but it doesn’t seem to change anything.

```
wchar_t receivedContentUtf[4086];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, receivedContent, -1, receivedContentUtf, 4086);
MessageBox::Show(gcnew System::String(receivedContentUtf);
```

Comment: What is stopping you writing some code to replace \uXXXX with the characters you want? \uXXXX has nothing to do with UTF-8 by the way.

Comment: Are you intentionally using C++/CLI? `gcnew` is not standard C++, and there's a C++-compatible [MessageBoxW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) function that can take a `wchar_t[]` directly.

Comment: @john Well, I could just replace those \uXXXX with appropriate characters, but I need more than only few characters, like diacritics from just one language.  Basically, this function should be able to properly read whatever UTF character server throws at it.
I don’t exactly know if it is UTF/encoding related, or not, but for me it looks like it affects for example diacritic characters and cyrillic characters, so I assumed that there is problem with that.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, I’m using this intentionally. MessageBox is only a example that I’m currently using for testing if this function returns proper characters, or not.
This data will be then parsed and stored in other form components.

Comment: But these aren't UTF-8 characters. All you have to do is convert the four digit hex number and store it in a `wchar_t`. Store all the ASCII chars in a wchar_t and as well, and you're done.

Comment: @user3017072: Wait a minute. Do you mean that you literally get 6 characters like `\ u 2 0 A C` ? And those aren't present in your original 8 bits input?!

Comment: @MSalters that's what I'm assuming, if it's not correct then ignore everything I've said.

Comment: @MSalters Server sends string containing diacritic character, for example: `“słowo”`. InternetReadFile() reads that like this: `“s\u0142owo”`. I want to get this back to original `“słowo”`. That’s it.

Comment: @user3017072: That's a rather ambiguous notation. How many characters are there in `"s\u0142owo"` according to `strlen()`? 5 or 10? Also, the server sends an encoded response, are you sure that the server is REALLY sending słowo and not s\u0142owo?

Comment: @user3017072 Probably it's too late now, but MSalters has asked the crucial question (twice now), and you've failed to answer either time. Unfortunately it's not clear what you have got or where you are trying to get to.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, I’m sure that server sends proper characters.

Comment: @john It should be clear what I’m trying to achieve when I asked the question. I even explained for the second time what kind of problem I have. And yes, it’s too late. I was able to find solution.

Thank you both for your time and effort.

Comment: @user3017072 I'm still not clear whether \u0142 was really 6 characters (my initial assumption) or whether it was an artifact of the way you were displaying your characters (I think MSalters initial assumption). Sorry to sound frustrated but whenever questions about encoding happen on this site it always proves impossible to get this kind of ambiguity sorted out. Still glad it was sorted in the end. If it's not too much to ask I'd be interested to know how you did it.